# How to download calendar from gmail using c#.net?

Tags: c#, windows, calendar, gmail-api

I am working on desktop email application. I want to download Gmail Calendar. It was working fine with following code. But since few days, it's not working. I have referred some of example but I am not getting result.
This is my existing code.

```
public static object GoogleCalenderData(string AccUser, string Pass)
{
    //Create a CalenderService and authenticate
    CalendarService service = new CalendarService("appname");
    service.setUserCredentials(AccUser, Pass);
    EventQuery query = new EventQuery()
    {
        Uri = new Uri(String.Format("http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/{0}/private/full", service.Credentials.Username)),
        StartTime = DateTime.Now
    };

    EventFeed myResultsFeed = service.Query(query);
    var googleEvents = myResultsFeed.Entries.Cast<EventEntry>();
    string val = string.Empty;
    val = string.Empty;
    foreach (var googleEvent in googleEvents)
    {
        val += "Title: " + googleEvent.Title.Text;
        val += "\n";
        val += "Contents =" + googleEvent.Content.Content;
        val += "\n";
        val += "Location = " + googleEvent.Locations.First().ValueString;
        val += "\n";
        val += "StartTime = " + googleEvent.Times.First().StartTime;
        val += "\n";
        val += "EndTime = " + googleEvent.Times.First().EndTime;
        val += "\n";
    }
    return val;
}
```

Comment: Explain "not working"

Answer (score 2):

The following code uses login and password ([ClientLogin](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/AuthForInstalledApps?csw=1)).  You cant use Login and password anymore to access Google APIs as far as I know it was shut down back in May 2015, I am surprised when you say it was working up until a few days ago.

```
service.setUserCredentials(AccUser, Pass);
```

You should be using oauth2, and while you are at it you should switch to the user version of the [Google Calendar API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/) and not use the old gData version.

Comment: @DalmTo Actually I have coded in 2014, then I didn't check. I check before few days and it wasn't working. Can you suggest me changes in it or any link which contain example.

Comment: @DalmTo Thank you. I have tried. 
I am getting following error : 
Inner Exception : 
{"Could not load file or assembly 'Google.Apis.PlatformServices, Version=1.9.3.19381, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=4b01fa6e34db77ab' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)":"Google.Apis.PlatformServices, Version=1.9.3.19381, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=4b01fa6e34db77ab"}

Comment: @DalmTo : I have passed this information. nj@gmail.com is my email id.
String CLIENT_ID = "92172322197-xxxx1mk3nk3phqaejscni531taf0an6f.apps.googleusercontent.com";
String CLIENT_SECRET = "QmprhxW7xxxxeVJvQXwp6m61";
service = Authentication.AuthenticateOauth(CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET, "nj@gmail.com");

Comment: And I get error here : 
//Authentication.cs
UserCredential credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(new ClientSecrets { ClientId = clientId, ClientSecret = clientSecret }, scopes, userName,CancellationToken.None, new FileDataStore("Store", false)).Result;

Comment: you should post a new question with errors you are having, as is unrated to your first question. .  And I think you should read the tutorial instead of just copying the code pasting your email into AuthenticateOauth isn't going to work.

Comment: Thank you. I will take care of it.

Comment: @DalmTo. I have gone through. It ask for authentication from browser firsttime. I have set authentication in windows form for Contact-Group functionality. Can I set authentication in Windows form?